# RabbitMQ architecture for jobs with results back

Tags: rabbitmq

I have trying to create a system that people can submit files to sign. Each submission can have multiple files and the results will be sent back to the user if once all the file in each submission is done.

Currently I have 6 signing boxes that signs one single file at a time. So for each submission I need to separate all the files and load balancing them among the 6 signing boxes, and after that I need to fetch the results and keep track of whether all the files in this submission have been completed.

If possible, I want to also limit the maximum number of signing boxes that each submission can use so that a big submission does not starve the other jobs.

My current set up is that I have a submission queue and a few submission queue consumers will consume message from it one by one, break the submission into individual files and send them to a file queue. And the 6 signing boxes will be the 6 consumers for the file queue. I am having trouble writing results back the the submission consumer which keep track of whether all the files are done for this submission, neither can I control the maximum number of signing boxes used for each job.

I looked at the RPC setup for rabbitmq which allows the results to be written back. The problem is rpc call is blocking for each file, and I want multiple files for the same submission to be able to sign in parallel. So I need some suggestions on the rabbitmq architecture and message flow for this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1) Assuming that you know the # of files, assign each submission a job id

2) A job can be composed of multiple tasks.

3) Calculate a priority which naively can be an inverse of the no of documents. So a document with more # of documents by default has a lower priority. Your application should have the bells and whistles to tweak the priority, just in case a bigger job needs to be processed with high priority.

4) Instead of coupling the job submitter and signer, why not use an event based mechanism that emits events on sign success and failure or currently processing for each task.

The submitter would persist the job and task details and the signer would update them as they get processed. The submitter would take into account the priority and no of tasks currently executing before submitting any further tasks. The logic to make that call is left to you.